# Jquery: rebind function on A link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, bind, unbind

I have a menu that shows on click (similar to the fb mobile menu). When you click anywhere on the viewport, the menu hides again and the link is disabled (i want to unbind the link because the a links on my viewport will not work without this click function unbound)

However, when i click the showmenu button, i want to be able to bind the viewport click again.

```
$(function(){
var menuStatus;

$("a.showMenu").click(function(){
    if(menuStatus != true){             
    $("#menu").animate({
        height: "44px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
      return false;
      } else {
        $("#menu").animate({
        height: "0px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
        return false;
      }
});
$("#viewport").bind('click.navclose', function(){ 
$(this).unbind('click.navclose');  
if(menuStatus = true){     
        $("#menu").animate({
        height: "0px",
      }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
        return false;
    }
});

});
```

Comment: can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: yes of course, http://jsfiddle.net/8NA8S/

Comment: i feel i'm not getting your question correctly, actually what do you mean by `bind`?

Comment: i'd like the nav to close everytime the body(viewport) is clicked... it works only once at the moment... the click function needs to unbind first so that the a.links i have within the body work. (the click function overrides the click of the link)

Comment: Try my answer, look at the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope will make sense

```
$(function() {
    var menuStatus;

    $("a.showMenu").click(function() {
        $("#viewport").bind('click', handler);
        if (menuStatus != true) {
            $("#menu").animate({
                height: "44px",
            }, 300, function() {
                menuStatus = true
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#menu").animate({
                height: "0px",
            }, 300, function() {
                menuStatus = false
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("#viewport").bind('click', handler);

    var handler = function() {
        $(this).unbind('click');
        if (menuStatus = true) {
            $("#menu").animate({
                height: "0px",
            }, 300, function() {
                menuStatus = false
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});​
```

[look at the updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/8NA8S/2/)